# Is it colloquial to say "you brush vertically the inner and outer sides of your teeth, then horizontally the chewing surfaces of your teeth"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Do we say "**vertically**", "**horizontally**", "**the inner/outer sides of teeth**", "**chewing surfaces of teeth**" in everyday conversations?

Is it colloquial to say "**you brush vertically the inner and outer sides of your teeth, then horizontally the chewing surfaces of your teeth**"?

Some suggest to say "**up and down**" and "**back and fort**".

Then, does it make sense to say "**you brush up and down the inner and outer sides of your teeth, then back and fort the chewing surfaces of your teeth**"?

Comment: It's 'back and _forth_', not 'fort'. 'Vertical' and 'horizontal' are perfectly acceptable words which most people will understand, but 'up and down' and 'back and forth' are more 'everyday' expressions.

Comment: The phrase is "back and fort**h**". We don't talk about how we brush our teeth in general conversation, but I would move the direction of brushing to after the word 'teeth'.

Comment: The message from my dentist is more like *Don't bother brushing your actual teeth. All that really matters is **cleaning the gum-line***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica IIRC my dentist told me to brush with circular motions, but it's possible that this was to ensure proper cleaning of the gum lines. Then again, this is the ELL StackExchange, not the medical science StackExchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you a full answer:

- *Vertically/horizontally* are fine, though slightly formal.
- *Up and down/back and forth* are more natural in informal conversation, though I would probably say *in and out* to my children rather than *back and forth*.

The most natural way I can think of right now would be:

- You brush the front of your teeth and behind your teeth up and down, and you brush the tops and bottoms with an in-and-out motion.

Usually, you would be demonstrating the motion with your hand or with a toothbrush while saying this, so the exact words wouldn't be so important.